# Loky-backed parallel loops cannot be nested below threads, setting n_jobs=1

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pickle, nested-loops

I am trying to unpickle 6 pickle files including one KNN clasifier and 2 Random forest classifiers:

```
import pickle
    pkl_filename = "./isrest.pkl"
    with open(pkl_filename, 'rb') as file:  
        restornot = pickle.load(file)
    .
    .
    .

    pkl_filename = "./thumborindexfilter.pkl"
    with open(pkl_filename, 'rb') as file:  
        thumborindexfilter = pickle.load(file)
```

then use them in an if loop this way:

```
ftr = np.array([features_extraction_csp(raw_data,restornotfilter)])
    if (restornot.predict(ftr) == 0):
        ftr2 = np.array([features_extraction_csp(raw_data,middleornotfilter)])
        if(middleornot.predict(ftr2) == 0):
            ftr3 = np.array([features_extraction_csp(raw_data,thumborindexfilter)])
            if(thumborindex.predict(ftr3) == 0):
                print("thumb")
                x = {"prediction": str(0) }
                y = json.dumps(x)
                return y  
            else:
                print("index")
                x = {"prediction": str(1) }
                y = json.dumps(x)
                return y  
        else:
            print("middle")
            x = {"prediction": str(2) }
            y = json.dumps(x)
            return y
    else:
        print("rest")
        x = {"prediction": str(3) }
        y = json.dumps(x)
        return y
```

Yet i'm getting this error:

```
    UserWarning: Loky-backed parallel loops cannot be nested below threads, setting n_jobs=1
  n_jobs = min(effective_n_jobs(n_jobs), n_estimators)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever solve this?